# @font-face not working at all with three different formats

Tags: asp.net, css, fonts

I have seen so many questions relevant to this,and also i tried them too,but none of them helped me.
   I have downloaded a font and placed it inside my project folder in asp.net.
   I called that font using @font-face.
   But it never works.
   I gave reference for all the three formats of fonts namely `.eot`,`.otf`,`.ttf`.
   Can anybody help me to fix this..

**CSS**

```
@font-face
        {
            font-family: MyriadPro-Regular;
            font-style: normal;
            src: url('Fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.ttf'),
                 url('Fonts/myriadpro-regular.eot'),
                 url('Fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf');
        }
```

[image]
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Check in the browser's network tab to see if it's throwing an error regarding the font files...

Comment: No i have checked all the three browsers..Console is clear..

Comment: Have you double checked the path? And is the website live to have a look at?

Comment: NO its not live..i have pasted an image showing folder and path in the question..have a look

Answer (score 0):

You have to check VS version and its compatibility with the font you downloaded.

Comment: OTF:1.006,ttf-2.037,for .eot there is no version